Child controlling alien/robot from inside
There was a movie I watched when I was only a kid, can't remember much but it was about a robot/alien who can take a child inside him, and let the child control him.
I only remember a scene where they are by the lakeside and kid was exploring the robots features, like he can piss(sorry about this) without getting out of him, and kid asked for food, they found a hamburger (dunno where/how they have found it) and robo thing grinded it, made it fluid for kid to eat. 
All I remember is these. I assume it was from 90s or 80s. 
It has been on my mind for a long time but can't remember any other thing about the movie. Would be nice to watch it again. Help would be appreciated !

Sounds like Star Kid from 1997:

Shy seventh-grader Spencer Griffith's life changes when a meteor falls into a local junkyard and he finds a Cybersuit - an exoskeleton with AI from another galaxy. Spencer puts on the Cybersuit and becomes a different kind of person. 

At some point, the robo-suit transforms a hamburger into a tasteless sludge for the kid, and here's the scene involving urination inside the robo-suit.
